# How can I access the host's eno1 network within my Docker containers?

Tags: docker, networking, iptables

I have a host with multiple network interfaces. An `eth0` which is the primary network interface that's connected to the Internet and a secondary `eno1` private network that's basically a switch connected to the host using a USB-Ethernet adapter.

In this configuration, is there a way I can access the devices connected to the switch (`172.16.0.0/22`) from within the Docker containers but without starting the containers with `--net=host`? I want the containers to be isolated so using `--net=host` would break that.

However, I also want to be able to communicate with devices connected to `eno1` from within my Docker containers.

One way I could potentially achieve this is by having a service running on the Docker host, bound to the host's `docker0` IP address and have all containers connected over Docker's default bridge network use the service running on the host as a proxy to reach the devices connected to `eno1`

Is there another way? Something similar to `--net=host` but instead of sharing the host's network entirely, I could choose to only share the `172.16.0.0/22` subnet?

---

Output of `ip -4 a` on the host:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.91.44.20/22 brd 10.91.47.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.16.0.1/22 brd 172.16.3.255 scope global noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    inet 240.10.0.1/24 brd 240.10.0.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of `ip -4 a` on the container:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
243: eth0@if244: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
    inet 240.10.0.2/24 brd 240.10.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of `nc -zv 172.16.3.1 5555` on the host:

```
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 172.16.3.1:5555.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.02 seconds.
```

`nc -zv 172.16.3.1 5555` fails to connect in the container when it's started with the command:

```
docker run -d --rm --init --privileged --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --name=test -i my-image:latest
```

`nc -zv 172.16.3.1 5555` connects successfully in the container when it's started with the command:

```
docker run -d --rm --init --privileged --net=host --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --name=test -i my-image:latest

docker exec -it test sh -c 'nc -zv 172.16.3.1 5555'
172.16.3.1 (172.16.3.1:5555) open
```

On the host:

```
$ sudo iptables -S FORWARD
-P FORWARD DROP
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT

$ ip route
default via 10.91.44.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 20
default via 10.91.44.1 dev eno1 proto static metric 40
10.91.44.0/22 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.91.44.20 metric 20
10.91.44.1 dev eno1 proto static scope link metric 40
172.16.0.0/22 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.0.1 metric 40
240.10.0.0/24 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 240.10.0.1
```

On the container:

```
$ ip route
default via 240.10.0.1 dev eth0
240.10.0.0/24 dev eth0 scope link  src 240.10.0.2
```

---

What I'm trying to do is connect to 172.16.3.1:5555 from within the container without having to start the container with `--net=host`.

Comment: Nothing stops programs in your docker container communicating with outside network resources: that's why you can `curl google.com` inside a Docker container. Similarly, if your host is connected to some network via the `eno1` interface, your containers should be able to access services on that network without any additional configuration. If something is *not* working, please provide us with specific details about what you're trying to do, what your network configuration looks like, and how the operation is failing.

Comment: @larsks Thanks. I've updated my question and added more details about the network config and output of `ip -4 a` along with what I'm trying to do and what's failing. Please let me know if anything else would help as well.

Comment: First, I would just remove that last `ip -4 a` output; given that you're running with `--net=host` the output isn't a surprise (you already show the host interface configuration earlier). What might be interesting is the output of `iptables -S FORWARD` on the host, and the output of `ip route` run both on the host and in the container.

Comment: @larsks Thanks. I added the output of both those commands run on the host and the container.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to achieve your goal is to use **macvlan** network driver for Docker. This driver allows you to create a virtual network interface for each container that is directly attached to the physical network interface of the host. This way, the containers can communicate with the devices on the eno1 network as if they were directly connected to the switch, without using the host as a proxy or sharing the host's network namespace.

### Explanation

The **macvlan** network driver creates a sub-interface of the host's physical network interface and assigns it a unique MAC address and an IP address from the same subnet as the host. The sub-interface is then attached to the container's network namespace, allowing the container to send and receive packets on the physical network. The host acts as a bridge between the sub-interfaces and the physical network interface, but it does not perform any routing or NAT for the containers.

To use the **macvlan** network driver, you need to create a **macvlan** network with Docker and specify the parent network interface and the subnet that you want to use for the containers. For example, if your host's eno1 interface has the IP address 172.16.0.1/22 and you want to use the range 172.16.0.128/25 for the containers, you can create a **macvlan** network with the following command:

```py
docker network create -d macvlan \
  --subnet=172.16.0.0/22 \
  --gateway=172.16.0.1 \
  --ip-range=172.16.0.128/25 \
  -o parent=eno1 \
  eno1_net
```

This command creates a **macvlan** network named eno1_net with the specified parameters. The -o parent option specifies the physical network interface to use for the **macvlan** network. The --subnet, --gateway, and --ip-range options specify the network configuration for the containers. You can use any valid IP addresses from the same subnet as the host, but make sure they do not conflict with the host's IP address or any other devices on the network.

Once you have created the **macvlan** network, you can run containers on it by using the --network option with the network name. For example, to run a container with the image ubuntu:18.04 on the **macvlan** network, you can use the following command:

```py
docker run -it --network eno1_net ubuntu:18.04
```

This command runs a container with an interactive shell and attaches it to the eno1_net network. The container will have an IP address from the range 172.16.0.128/25 and will be able to communicate with the devices on the eno1 network as well as the internet via the eth0 interface of the host.

### Example

To demonstrate the use of the **macvlan** network driver, let us assume that you have a host with two network interfaces: eth0 and eno1. The eth0 interface is connected to the internet and has the IP address 192.168.1.10/24. The eno1 interface is connected to a switch and has the IP address 172.16.0.1/22. The switch has two other devices connected to it: a printer with the IP address 172.16.0.2 and a laptop with the IP address 172.16.0.3.

You want to run a container that can access the printer and the laptop on the eno1 network, but also the internet via the eth0 interface. You also want to isolate the container from the host's network namespace. To achieve this, you can use the following steps:

1. Create a **macvlan** network with the parent eno1 and the IP range 172.16.0.128/25:

```py
docker network create -d macvlan \
  --subnet=172.16.0.0/22 \
  --gateway=172.16.0.1 \
  --ip-range=172.16.0.128/25 \
  -o parent=eno1 \
  eno1_net
```

2. Run a container with the image ubuntu:18.04 on the **macvlan** network:

```py
docker run -it --network eno1_net ubuntu:18.04
```

3. Inside the container, verify the network configuration with the ip command:

```py
root@b0f0a8f0a0f0:/# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: eth0@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:10:00:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.16.0.128/22 brd 172.16.3.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

You can see that the container has an eth0 interface with the IP address 172.16.0.128/22, which is from the **macvlan** network.

4. Ping the printer and the laptop on the eno1 network:

```py
root@b0f0a8f0a0f0:/# ping 172.16.0.2
PING 172.16.0.2 (172.16.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.386 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.325 ms
^C
--- 172.16.0.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.325/0.355/0.386/0.034 ms
root@b0f0a8f0a0f0:/# ping 172.16.0.3
PING 172.16.0.3 (172.16.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.421 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.0.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.358 ms
^C
--- 172.16.0.3 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.358/0.389/0.421/0.036 ms
```

You can see that the container can ping the printer and the laptop on the eno1 network successfully.

5. Ping a website on the internet via the eth0 interface of the host:

```py
root@b0f0a8f0a0f0:/# ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.74.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 142.250.74.238: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=14.9 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.74.238: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=14.9 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.900/14.900/14.900/0.000 ms
```

You can see that the container can ping a website on the internet via the eth0 interface of the host successfully.

6. Exit the container and verify that the host's network configuration is unchanged:

```py
root@b0f0a8f0a0f0:/# exit
exit
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:12:34:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.10/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 86397sec preferred_lft 86397sec
3: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:68:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.0.1/22 brd 172.16.3.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

You can see that the host's network configuration is unchanged and the host still has the IP addresses 192.168.1.10/24 and 172.16.0.1/22 on the eth0 and eno1 interfaces respectively. The host is not aware of the container's IP address or the **macvlan** network.

### Summary

In this answer, we have explained how to use the **macvlan** network driver for Docker to achieve your goal of accessing the devices on the eno1 network from within the containers without using the host as a proxy or sharing the host's network namespace. We have also provided an example of how to create and use a **macvlan** network with Docker and how to verify the network configuration of the container and the host. We hope this answer was helpful and informative.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will have to try this out tomorrow but meanwhile I was able to resolve the issue I was facing by reading through Docker docs, especially the [part about default behaviour where traffic from containers connected to the default Docker bridge is **not** forwarded](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#disconnect-a-container-from-a-user-defined-bridge). I ran `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1` and `sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT` on the host and my containers are now able to reach devices connected to **eno1** (as well as the Internet)